# Minimalist Programming Tools

Tags: performance, frameworks

What tools go well with or help minimalist programming? Examples would be libraries with tight, clean interface and very small size in it's genre.

Techniques, functions or concepts that result in smaller and/or more efficient apps would be great. If you know of any other relevant tools this would help as well.

Comment: This isn't a particularly well specced question.  What would you count as minimalistic, and if you were truly minimal, why would you be including things like Java?

Comment: I don't use Java but I am looking to fill out my toolbox for situations where I go outside my usuall areas. Was not sure how to phrase this, I *am* looking for rather general answers. In my experience anyway all languages have their version of bloat and trim code.

Comment: A punch card and a fork?

Comment: You're still using forks? Real programmers use butterflies to cause eddies in the upper atmosphere deflecting cosmic rays to flip the required bits on a drive platter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be quite what you're looking for, but I enjoyed reading [A Whirlwind Tutorial on Creating Really Teensy ELF Executables for Linux](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html), which starts out with basic techniques for reducing bloat, before going into far more detail than I thought possible in order to shave every last byte from an executable!

Answer (score 1):

if not assembler, then almost any Forth.

Answer (score 0):

See [colorFORTH](https://web.archive.org/web/20160414102635/http://colorforth.com/) - minimal *and* strange ... best of both worlds :)